# iOS webview event when remote html file finish loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

When I load an .html file into webview using following method and finish its load, an event `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {` is fired.

```
[webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"/files/myFile" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

However, if I load same file remotely, that event is not fired! why? How could I do it? Thank you.

```
[webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlBase stringByAppendingString:@".html"]]]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is because of an error during the load.

Try and define the delegate method `– webView:didFailLoadWithError:` and see what happens (if it is called instead of didFinish)...

Comment: that's it! I appreciate so much your help!